# Performing arithmetic on pandas columns based on a different column's value being referenced against a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
  product  currency  price  
    a       USD       2
    b       AUD       3
    c       GBP       9
   ....
```

and I have a dict:

```
cc={"USD": 1, "AUD":.75, "GBP: 1.13}
```

I want to change the price by multiplying the price times the value corresponding to the currency in the CC dict so I tried:

```
df.price.apply(lambda x: x*cc[df['currency']])
```

Which gives the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map (make sure all values in that Series are also in the dict):

```
df['currency'].map(cc) * df['price']
Out: 
0     2.00
1     2.25
2    10.17
dtype: float64
```

If you want to change the price column, assign it back:

```
df['price'] = df['currency'].map(cc) * df['price']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'USD', 2L],
                   ['b', 'AUD', 3L],
                   ['c', 'GBP', 9L]],
                  columns=['product', 'currency', 'price'])

cc = pd.Series({"USD": 1, "AUD":.75, "GBP": 1.13})

df.price *= cc.ix[df.currency].values

df
```

[image]